# Get date input from html and compare in php

Tags: php, html, datetime

I have an field input="date" in html form and i want to compare the selected date with the current date in php but it s not working

```
$datan=$_POST['birthday'];
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest'); 
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d"); 
if(($currentdate-$datan)/365>=18) 
{
 ---do something 
}
else echo " Your age is below 18 !"
```

Comment: Which message? :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: @Wimanicesir what??

Comment: @Dave it's totally not the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value from your form arrives in the yyyy-mm-dd format leverage the functions PHP supplies for dealing with dates.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest'); 
$datan    = new DateTime($_POST['birthday']);
$rightnow = new DateTime();
$interval = $datan->diff($rightnow,true);
if ($interval->format('%y') > 18) { 
    echo 'Your age is over 18'; 
} else {
    echo 'Your age is below 18!';
}
```